# Как преобразовать строку в дату? 20180819 -> 2018-08-19

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

Направьте на правильный путь, а то я совсем запутался.

Есть строка `text = "20180819"`, а на выходе хочу получить `2018-08-19`

Чтобы потом создать иерархию папок с такими названиями:
`2018/2018-08/2018-08-19`

Использую библиотеку datetime, но у меня получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime as DT

text = "20180819"

date = DT.datetime.strptime(text, '%Y%m%d').date()
print(date)                       # 2018-08-19
print(str(date))                  # 2018-08-19
print(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))  # 2018-08-19
```

---

Чтобы сгенерировать путь, можно так извернуться:

```
import os

dirs_path = '/'.join(date.strftime(fmt) for fmt in ['%Y', '%Y-%m', '%Y-%m-%d'])
print(dirs_path)  # 2018/2018-08/2018-08-19

# Генерация пути используя системные разделители
dirs_path = os.path.sep.join(date.strftime(fmt) for fmt in ['%Y', '%Y-%m', '%Y-%m-%d'])
print(dirs_path)  # 2018\2018-08\2018-08-19
```

Чтобы создать папки:

```
# Создаем если такого пути нет
if not os.path.exists(dirs_path):
    os.makedirs(dirs_path)
```

Comment: Генерировать путь можно сразу в выходном формате `strftime('%Y/%Y-%m/%Y-%m-%d', date_var)`

Comment: @Lecron, согласен, ваш вариант проще :) Добавьте себе его :)

Answer (score 5):

В общих случаях работы с датой, получение из строки и обратно, делается так:

```
import time

dt = time.strptime('20180819', '%Y%m%d')
print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', dt))  # -> '2018-08-19'
```

создать папки можно так:

```
from pathlib import Path

path_str = time.strftime('%Y/%Y-%m/%Y-%m-%d', dt)
Path(path_str).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

однако в данном конкретном случае, можно обойтись срезами

```
s = '20180819'
year = s[:4]
month = s[4:6]
day = s[6:]
print(f'{year}/{year}-{month}/{year}-{month}-{day}')
```